# How to delete fields using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problem with my jquery script. I have code like this and my script is deleting only input not label with it. How to delete also label?

```
<div class="input_fields_container">
        @foreach($data->videoTags as $tag)
        <div class="el">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-2 control-label bold">@lang('main.position')</label>
          <div class="col-lg-6 input-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="" name="tag[]" value="{{$tag->tag}}" class="form-control">
          <div class="input-group-btn inup-group-addon"><a href="#" class="remove_field" style="margin-left:10px;">@lang('main.delete')</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  @endforeach
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.input_fields_container').on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text links
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parents().eq(1).remove();
      x--;
  })
});
</script>
```

Comment: In terms of the parents of the `remove_field` element, what parent is it you want to remove?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `closest()` to target the parent div that contain the `label` also :

```
$(this).closest('.form-group').remove();
//OR
$(this).closest('.form-group').html('');
```

**NOTE :** You could jump up to the `el` parent you need just to change the selector.

Answer (score 0):

The use of the selector eq here is not very wise. You can check the doc to understand how to use it efficiently :

https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

You can read:

*"They narrow the set down based on the order of the elements within this matched set. For example, if elements are first selected with a class selector (.myclass) and four elements are returned, these elements are given indices 0 through 3 for the purposes of these selectors."*

By doing `$(this).parent().eq(1).remove()`, you will remove only one element of the array of element that match the selection of `$(this).parent()`. You can check what is in your array to try to understand what to remove.

I suggest that you can use your foreach to create a attribute like "data-input=y" on your `<div class="el">`, where y is a variable that you increment. Like that you can quickly know which input to delete and your selection is not depending of the structure of the DOM.